# How do I show a sign up/log in field when hovering over it

Tags: html, css, hover

```css
#aanmelden:hover {

}

#inloggen:hover {

}
```

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
 <li id="aanmelden"><a href="#">Sign Up</a></li>
 <li id="inloggen"><a href="#">Log In</a></li>
 </ul>
```

When you hover over Log In/Sign Up it will have to show a registration/login form. 
Do I have to hide the form first and when I hover show them?
The login/sign up form will overlap a slideshow.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HTML

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="aanmelden"><a href="#">Sign Up</a>
            <div class="drop">
                <input type="text">
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="inloggen"><a href="#">Log In</a>
             <div class="drop">
                <input type="text">
            </div>
           </li>
    </ul>
```

CSS

```
.drop{
    display: none;
}
li:hover .drop{
    display: block;
}
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/6woxm6x0/)